# Wrong Timing relative to Windows Message Loop in 3D appli?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, 3d, redraw

I have got a Pb  possibly with timing in regards of the Windows Message Loop, I think (?):

While Manipulating a 3D scene drawn under (OpenGL + C++) for Windows, I want that  in response to a WM_ LBUTTONDOWN  user event , to change continuously the camera  position from a point A to point B ( but with same lookAt point). I would like also a ~ 2sec duration for that move:

In my OnLButtonDown()  handler for WM_ LBUTTONDOWN message, I enter a 100 iterations loop like this:

{ m_camera.setEyePos(...pos #i...);

SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_PAINT,0,0);}

ending at  the desired camera position.

> > BUT my scene isn't redrawned at all in the 99 intermediate states: 
> >     It is just redrawn in the final position! (but in a correct way)
> >     it jump directly from the initial point of view to the final one! (but it takes 2sec to do so, as intended..)

What's  wrong?
Can you help? Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my English (I am French..) ...and beginner with Windows programming...

Comment: What is a `Pb`? The only thing that comes to mind is lead.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with this approach. If you are iterating in a loop 100 times then you are not processing Windows messages. So you won't process the WM_PAINT until you leave the loop. Then there is the problem that WM_PAINT has a clipping region associated with it, known only to the operating system, so it is never valid to send the message yourself. Instead, call InvalidateRect to request the operating system to generate a WM_PAINT. You should do this from a timer or from your game loop so that messages will continue to be processed.

Comment: @ ScottMc , OK but I tried: InvalidateRect(m_hWnd,NULL,true);
UpdateWindow(m_hWnd)==0); within my loop , BUT it didn't change anything..??? I dont understand.

Comment: Same as before: The WM_PAINT will not be processed while you are in your loop. Windows will not interrupt your loop. It only sends the message when your app is waiting for a message.

Comment: You mean I CAN'T repaint from WITHIN my Loop, even with InvalidateRect? In that case how ELSE can I do?...

Comment: You CAN paint within your loop. But not by generating WM_PAINT. Just call GetDC and paint using that DC.

Comment: It doesnt work either with this  i-loop
 {...m_Camera.Set EyePos(...   pos #i ...) 
 UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);
 hDC = GetDC(m_hWnd); 
 OnPaint(hDC);
 ReleaseDC(m_hWnd,hDC);  
 }
However  now after precise testing , I am SURE  that my  usual Onpaint() handler IS really executed  100 times!!!  but no INTERMEDIATE redraw draw  occurs! ????    Madness!
And this OnPaint() handler is the same one I use for handling WM_PAINT message:
case WM_PAINT:
 hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
 OnPaint(hDC);
 EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
 break;